# Fill ComboBox with names of files from a directory on FTP server

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, ftpwebrequest

I have a file folder in my FTP server and I want to fill a `ComboBox` with the contents inside of that folder. How would I go about doing this?

```
string result = string.Empty;

//Request location and server name---------->
FtpWebRequest request = 
    (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://*******" +"/" + "Products" + "/");

//Lists directory
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;

// set credentials
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1","1234");
//initialize response
FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

//reader to read response
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream);
combobox1.Text = FTP_Server();
//data from file.
result = reader.ReadToEnd();
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

Thanks! I didn't know if this was even possible!

Answer (score 2):

Read the listing by lines:

```
FtpWebRequest request = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("ftp://example.com/remote/path/");
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");

comboBox1.BeginUpdate();
try
{
    using (FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            comboBox1.Items.Add(reader.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
finally
{
    comboBox1.EndUpdate();
}
```

---

*Downloading whole listing to a string and splitting it afterwards (as suggested by the other answer) can be pretty ineffective, if there's lot of entries.*

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact format of your response string, my instinct would be to split the response string:

```
string files[] = result.Split("\r\n");
```

Then to iterate over the individual files, adding them to your combobox1's `Items`:

```
// Depending on how many items you're adding, you may wish to prevent a repaint until the operation is finished
combobox1.BeginUpdate();
foreach(string file in files)
{
    combobox1.Items.Add(file);
}
combobox1.EndUpdate();
```

That should take care of it for you! There is some excellent (and exhaustive) documentation on MSDN as well, which will often contain some usage examples to help you out further: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples

Note that, if you end up wanting to display information from a different FTP response, you'll have to clear the combobox1 like so first: `combobox1.Items.Clear();`

Comment: Happy to help @JonHorn! Remember to accept the answer if it ends up getting you what you need :)